# checkboxes on submit not showing correct values. Shows 0 always

Tags: 7, forms

I am working with a form which contains list of checkboxes based on country. checkboxes are rendered correctly. But on submit, I don't get checkboxes' correct values. It always gets submitted as NOT CHECKED. My code is as below:

```
    foreach($fields as $id=>$title) {
          $form['test'.$code]['fields-'.$code] = array(
              '#type' => 'checkboxes',
              '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array_keys($fields)),
              '#title' => t('Title'),
              '#attributes' => array('name' => 'field-'.$code.'-'.$id),
          );
        }

    function config_submit($form, &$form_state) {
      var_dump($form_state['values']);
      exit;
    }
```

outputs :

```
array (size=13)
  'fields-dk' => 
    array (size=7)
      'title' => int 0
      'reason' => int 0
      'doc-reference' => int 0
      'description' => int 0
      'upload-claim-file' => int 0
      'product-detail' => int 0
      'barcode-num' => int 0
```

Why is it returning always as 0? What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using "checkboxes" for a yes/no, usually one would use a simple checkbox element.

Comment: @Vicky8888, its not Yes/No.. Its a list of fields. User can select which fields he wants to display.

Comment: When you use #options on a FAPI element the value passed to the $form_state is the array key, so you don't need to use array_keys().

Comment: @Vicky8888, I have just manipulated the array there to get expected titles for checkboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we can't see how your form is built completely, it might be that your custom attributes are affecting the element "name" in the form state.

i.e change

```
'#attributes' => array('name' => 'field-'.$code.'-'.$id),
```

to

```
'#attributes' => array('data-name' => 'field-'.$code.'-'.$id),
```

Comment: Hey, this does not give me 1 if checked but returns data-name if checkbox is selected... So now I can differentiate checked and non-checked checkboxes in Backend. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you're using JS or Ajax somewhere on the form? In any case, glad that helped.

Comment: No JS or Ajax is used. Its simple configuration page.

Comment: Ok, keep in mind checkboxes doesn't always return 1 for the value, it will return the key as the value instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the submission data with below:

```
$form_state['values']['checkboxes']; 

or

foreach($form_state['values']['checkboxes'] as $key=>$value){
  // your logic
}
```

I have used the below form field for checkbox

```
$form['checkboxes'] = array(
      '#type' => 'tableselect',
      '#header' => $build_table['#header'],
      '#options' => $build_table['#rows'],
      '#empty' => t('No records found.')
    );
```

Comment: it does not work :(